# Need Tomcat thread dump

Tags: java, dump

I'm Trying to have thread dump on tomcat 7 that running on Linux:

> ps -ef | grep tomcat
>
> kill -3 12354

i cannot find the output of the command

Comment: don't know about tomcat 7, but in tomcat 6 is was in catalina.out

Comment: cannot find catalina.out

Comment: that's in `{tomcat-home}/logs/`, e.g. `/opt/tomcat/logs/`

Comment: cannot find it in any log file!!!